# Eyes that work like mirror telescopes

Tags: biology, evolution, xenobiology, genetic-engineering, senses

So the thing is, I made a question regarding seeing all of the EM spectrum(or at least all that it's possible through biological means) and someone pointed out that the image would be distorted because each frequency has a different angle of refraction, but it turns out that lenses are not the only way to focus light, and we have mirror telescope exactly to solve this chromatic aberration problem.

So the question is: How could a biological eye that focus with biomirrors instead of lenses work?

Comment: Seems plausible, particularly considering many real animals have a reflective component in their eyes. I would also point out that the brain could probably do a fine job of correcting for chromatic aberration "in post".

Comment: @JBH Ok then, I edited the question to "how could this work" instead of "is it possible".

Comment: No, that doesn't answer his questions. Scallops can't resolve an image any more than general shapes. They use a nucleic just to reflect a very limited wavelength.

Just because it's possible doesn't mean it's a good idea. When you get too far outside of the visible spectrum, you run into opacity and transparency issues. The JWST works because it's in a vacuum. The wavelengths it's looking at are opaque to our atmosphere. Go too far in the other direction and you're dealing with materials incompatible with biological processes to avoid being completely transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is reasonable, and answerable.

Our eyes have pretty lousy optics off-axis. We use the very centre of our eyes for precision vision, and we have developed all kinds of mental tricks to ignore the aberrations.

Cats' eyes have a reflective back layer called the 'tapetum'. This makes better use of the light by adding a reflector behind the retina so the light passes through it twice. That is reflection optics of a sort.

If primitive eyes may have developed from a light sensitive patch and pinhole optics, like the nautilus. It is possible to imagine an alternative scenario where a shiny patch (fish scales?) reflected light onto the patch. You might use this for very deep-sea fish in fiction.

Evolution seems to have invented eyes many times. Our eyes have the nerves and blood vessels on top of the retina. An octopus has the more logical arrangement with the wiring underneath. Once we have a working eye, it seems to be very hard to go back and fix things like this.

Some drawbacks: mirrors require more precision than lenses, particularly with a low jump in refractive index, and liquid-filled optics such as our eyes are very robust.

How about a composite approach? Have a conventional eye with a mirror option for low light vision. Something like a peacock looking at its own tail fan.